# RxJS: Even if used `shareReplay()` on source observable, `throwError()` gets executed separately for each observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm using RxJS `shareReplay()` operator on an observable (`courses$`) to share observable stream among other two observables (`beginnerCourses$` and `advancedCourses$`). It's working fine and single API call response is shared between both observables on success.

But, when it comes to error, these observable don't share error and error is seen to be thrown twice in the browser console. Doesn't `shareReplay()` operator shares error also? Is it an intended behavior?

```js
const http$ = createHttpObservable('/api/courses');

const courses$ = http$
  .pipe(
    map(res => res['payload'] ),
    shareReplay(),
    catchError(err => {
      return throwError(err);
    })
  );

this.beginnerCourses$ = courses$
  .pipe(
    map(courses => courses
      .filter(course => course.category === 'BEGINNER')));

this.advancedCourses$ = courses$
  .pipe(
    map(courses => courses
      .filter(course => course.category === 'ADVANCED')));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the expected behavior, what's a bit *unexpected* is that you're getting 2 different errors.

`shareReplay` places a `ReplaySubject` between the data consumer(s) and the data producer. When an error notification arrives, the `ReplaySubject` in use will send the **same error** notification to all the **registered subscribers**:

```js
error(err: any) {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  }
  this.hasError = true;
  this.thrownError = err;
  this.isStopped = true;
  const { observers } = this;
  const len = observers.length;
  const copy = observers.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    copy[i].error(err);
  }
  this.observers.length = 0;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L72-L86)

but when using `shareReplay`, when an error occurs the `ReplaySubject` in use will be **replaced** by another one when a **new subscriber** is about to subscribe. Saying that it's being replaced, this also entails **re-subscribing to the source**.

So I think all the subscribers should receive the **same error notification** as long as they are already part of the `ReplaySubject`'s list of subscribers. Otherwise, when a new subscriber comes in, the source will be re-subscribed.

---

What you could do is to **prevent** the `ReplaySubject` from receiving **error notifications** and allow its subscribers to receive it as they are, is to use `materialize` and `dematerialize` operators:

```js
const courses$ = http$
  .pipe(
    materialize(), // Everything as a `next` notification
    map(res => res['payload'] ),
    shareReplay(),
    dematerialize() // Back to the original event
  );
```

With this approach, if a registered subscriber receives the error notification, it will be unsubscribed, meaning that it will also be removed from the `ReplaySubject`'s list of subscribers. But the `ReplaySubject` will still be there and will **not be replaced** on subsequent subscribers.

---

Also, I think this is pretty redundant:

```js
catchError(err => throwError(err));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behavior when an observable throws an error, shareReplay() will try  resubscribe/re-execute the source

you can try this to validate

```
const a=defer(()=>{
  console.log('run')
  return throwError(new Error('Error'))
}).pipe(shareReplay())

a.subscribe(console.log,console.error,()=>console.log('complete'))
a.subscribe(console.log,console.error,()=>console.log('complete'))
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jutfxe

If you want observable to share the error without execute again 
use `publishReplay(1),refCount()` instead