# Create a blocking behavior between subscriptions

Tags: promise, rxjs

I have created an observable from a promise using `defer`.

```
let connect$ = defer(() => connectAsync());
```

This will execute the `connectAsync` function each time I subscribe to `connect$`.
But I need it to wait until the previous subscription has been completed until the new subscription starts.

Here is some code with comments to make the behavior that I want more clear.

```
connect$.subscribe(); // --|>
connect$.subscribe(); //    --|>
connect$.subscribe(); //       --|>
```

Is there any rxjs operator or subject I can use to achieve behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Short Answer:

No, there's no such operator in the RxJS library

### The Long(er) Answer:

One of the cool things about the way RxJS curries operators is that it's fairly painless to create your own and RxJS will treat it the same way it handles any other operator.

For example:

```ts
function shareQueue<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>{
  let buffer: Observable<T> = EMPTY;
  return (s: Observable<T>) => defer(() => {
    buffer = concat(
      buffer.pipe(ignoreElements()),
      s
    ).pipe(
      share({
        resetOnError: () => EMPTY;
        resetOnComplete: () => EMPTY;
        resetOnRefCountZero: () => EMPTY;
      })
    );
    return buffer;
  });
}
```

You can then use it like this to get (what I think) you're after:

```ts
const connect$ = defer(connectAsync).pipe(
  shareQueue()
);

connect$.subscribe();
connect$.subscribe();
connect$.subscribe();
```

Comment: That's a nice way to solve this problem. Just tested it and works like a charm. Nice use of a buffer observable combined with ignoreElements. When testing I've seen the importance of the `share` operator in this curried operator. Can you please explain a bit what it does here?

Comment: @blueshell Sure, by necessity, each subscriber must wait for the buffer to clear. Observable aren't shared/hot/multicasted by default, since we might have any number of subsrcibers we need to make our buffer multicasted. Otherwise, the buffer will re-subscribe to the source multiple times per subscriber.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see it. It needs to be shared because that way the connectAsync observable will not be executed until the shared buffer has expired. Otherwise each subscription the connectAsync observable would be added to the buffer and it would be executed for as many times as there  have been subscribers. Thank you very much!

Comment: @blueshell Yeah, another way to think about it is that we're effectively creating a linked-list style buffer. `share` ensures we have a link back to just the previous node (instead of a link to **every** previous node). Since the nodes manage themselves (unsubscribe to their `prev` when they complete), it makes the whole thing deceptively simple :)

Comment: Just realized there is a caveat to this. Say we have 2 subscribers who have successfully executed the connectAsync observable. Because this is a promise, the observable completes and the buffer will be left with no subscribers. Because there are no subscribers, the buffer is no longer shared cfr. [share docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share). 
If later there is a third subscriber, all observables in the buffer (2 in this case) will be executed again. The solution I've used to this is to use `shareReplay` instead of `share`.

Comment: @blueshell I'm afraid the problem is worse than that! If you're using a newer version of RxJS, You can pass `share` a `ShareConfig` object. Otherwise, you still need to suppress buffered errors (as you don't care about them). You can use `catchError(() => EMPTY)` before `shareReplay`

Comment: I'm not (yet) using version 7.x.x of rxjs, as Angular 13 does not yet use this version. Using the  `catcherror` before `shareReplay` will suppress all errors, not only the buffered ones. I cannot use the `catchError` in the pipe with the ignoreElements either because then the `shareReplay` does will unsubscribe form the buffer.
For now, I'll use a hack with materialize before shareReplay, dematerialize after and again a materialize before the ignoreElements. As this will suppress the buffered errors only.
I'll definitely use the solution with the shareConfig once Angular uses rxjs 7.x.x.

Comment: @blueshell  What about `buffer.pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY), ignoreElements())`?

Comment: That won't work. Just like the `share` operator `shareReplay` also resubscribes to the source when it has thrown an error. I've read another [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61884807/13767130) about this. I do think that solution is quite ugly but it will do for now. Later I can use the prettier solution with the `ShareConfig` object.